# Need to store images in SQL Server, but how?

Tags: sql-server

In order to store images in a SQL Server database, I am working with a naive table. The table's columns are: `ImageID, X, Y, value`.

Table sample data:

```
[1 1 1 255] %first image, pixel (1,1)
[1 1 2 100] %first image, pixel (1,2)
[1 2 1 100] %first image, pixel (2,1)
[1 2 2 0]
[2 1 1 100] %second image, pixel (1,1)
[2 1 2 10]
```

I choose this specific way for storing images for executing queries such as:

```
select count(value) 
from myTable 
where myTable.x = 10 and myTable.y = 15 and myTable.value > 10
```

The problem is that I am running out of storage - the table is getting too big.
Do you have any suggestion for saving images more efficiently while maintaining the ability to executes queries like the mentioned above?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest not putting images in a relational database.

Comment: you may consider looking into this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416881/insert-picture-into-sql-server-2005-image-field-using-only-sql

Comment: why are you storing images in DB, is there a specific reason?

Comment: What's a naive table?

Comment: I choose this specific way for storing images for executing queries as mentiond above

Comment: naive is an adjective :), simple table if you wish

Comment: I am not using database simply for storage, i need to execute queries as mention  in the question. If i will not store the images i will need to load each image to answar such queries.

Answer (score 3):

I really feel that a database is the wrong way to handle this problem.  I would have, perhaps, a database of image locations and a server side component that can read the images from some sort of local store (i.e. a directory) and run something like ImageMagik to determine if a particular pixel in each image is a particular color.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625876/how-to-get-image-whole-pixels-rgb-color-with-imagemagick) might give you some ideas in that direction.